# Multi-lingual Webform, not entire website

Tags: 8, webforms, i18n-l10n

Our client does not need their entire website to be translated into multiple languages. However, they have a webform that provides a number of different languages in a dropdown, and would like the form labels to be displayed in the chosen language.

Creating multiple versions of the form would be a maintenance headache. Is there a way to tap into Webform and Drupal's localization facilities without the complexity of introducing it to the entire website, so just in the scope of the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to enable configuration translation to be able to easily translate webforms.

Comment: Thanks. I found by adding the languages but enabling very few of the options, I was able to translate the Webform without having an impact on the rest of the website. Webform is a fantastic module, by the way.